# Doctrine - Generating entities based on different base paths

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

My project has a modular folder structure, in the root there is a `modules` folder, and inside this folder there are more folders that each represent a module in my application. In turn, these folders each have a `src` folder, which then contain a folder representing the namespace the contained code represents.

eg:

```
./module
    ./Application
        ./src
            ./Application
                ./Controller
                ./Service
                ./View
    ./Products
        ./src
            ./Products
                ./Controller
                ./Service
                ./View
    ./Users
        ./src
            ./Users
                ./Controller
                ./Service
                ./View
```

My question is how can I configure Doctrine to generate entities, when running `doctrine orm:generate-entities` so that each module ends up with a `/src/NAMESPACE/Entities` folder? As it stands currently when I run this command, entites are generated like so:

```
./module
    ./Application
        ./Entities <-- generated by Doctrine
        ./src
            ./Application
                ./Controller
                ./Service
                ./View
    ./Products
        ./Entities <-- generated by Doctrine
        ./src
            ./Products
                ./Controller
                ./Service
                ./View
    ./Users
        ./Entities <-- generated by Doctrine
        ./src
            ./Users
                ./Controller
                ./Service
                ./View
```

But I want this:

```
./module
    ./Application
        ./src
            ./Application
                ./Controller
                ./Entities <-- generated by Doctrine
                ./Service
                ./View
    ./Products
        ./src
            ./Products
                ./Controller
                ./Entities <-- generated by Doctrine
                ./Service
                ./View
    ./Users
        ./src
            ./Users
                ./Controller
                ./Entities <-- generated by Doctrine
                ./Service
                ./View
```